# Error: No provider for MockBackend! when write unit test for angular2 final

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I'm writting unit test for angular2 - karma - jasmine.

I used `mockBackend` to response data when service call API.
This is my code

```
    function Connection(mockBackend) {
          connection.mockRespond(new Response(
              new ResponseOptions({
                      body: JSON.stringify(lookup)
                   }
              )));
        });
    }

describe('Update Contact Details Test', () => {
      let fixture, comp;

      beforeEach(async(inject([MockBackend], (mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
        Connection(mockBackend);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [ ContactFieldListComponent ],
                providers: _.union(DEFAULT_PROVIDERS, [FieldService, LookupsService, ContactService]),
                schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
                imports: DEFAULT_IMPORT
            })
            .compileComponents().then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContactFieldListComponent);
                comp = fixture.componentInstance;
            });
    })));

    it('get contact field list', () => 
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

It don't work with error `Error: No provider for MockBackend!`.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: What's the content of `DEFAULT_PROVIDERS`?

Comment: @Dinistro, `DEFAULT_PROVIDERS=[{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }, TranslateService, FormBuilder,DatePipe]`.

Comment: In this case, take a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you missed to add the MockBackend into the providers of the TestBed.

```
...
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ ContactFieldListComponent ],
            providers: _.union(
                DEFAULT_PROVIDERS, [
                    FieldService, 
                    LookupsService, 
                    ContactService,
                    MockBackend // <- add it here
                ]),
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
            imports: DEFAULT_IMPORT
        })
...
```

Additionally I think you have to create another beforeEach under the one with the `TestBed`, because in the first one, MockBackend isn't registered.

I have a sample test for you, that perhaps can help you: https://github.com/angular-workshops/angular2-testing/blob/solution/tour-of-heroes/src/app/hero.service/hero.service.shallow.spec.ts

Comment: @Sophia sorry, had a typo. Can you try again with `MockBackend` and if it's not working, add your new message.

Comment: yep I tried with `MockBackend` and it's not working with the same error ` Failed: No provider for MockBackend!`